# Redundant safety in php or/and javascript

Tags: php

I work a lot with php and javascript, and I have been wondering if I have redundant safety in my code, for example around line 10 I have things like the code below

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    header("Location: ./?error=1"); exit;
}
```

And then further down inside a javascript I have `var battleId = "<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['id']); ?>";` is code like that redundant? I been thinking since I already checked on top of the page, `$_GET['id']` can't be a number, since then they wouldn't reach the javascript code.

The same goes for my MySQL calls, it can look something like this

```
$checkCharacter = getServer() -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `battle_character` WHERE `character_id`=:characterId AND `battle_id`=:battleId");
$checkCharacter -> bindParam(":characterId", $c->getId());
$checkCharacter -> bindParam(":battleId", $_GET['id']);
$checkCharacter -> execute();
```

Is it necessary for me to use prepare and bindParam, when I know the get have already been checked at the top of the page, and the object `$c->getId()` can't be anything but a number, and more to the point. Do those extra safety codes slow down the site more then helping?

Comment: I personally recommend to always escape/validate/check at all possible injection places in the code. Think about that when you change something in the future, for example you remove the redirect for some reason. Than you can be sure that all your existing code is secure.

Comment: Your desire to avoid parameter binding stems from the detoury method you're using for it. Just write a proper wrapper function to PDO, or at least utilize `->execute([...])`. Same goes for the html escaping; use a leaner function, then it looks less redundant and effortful. There are more ways to *simplify* input verification. Consolidation over eschewing! The more the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using prepared statements, which is great and good practice. Continue to do that. The performance hit of isset, is_numeric or htmlentities is negligible and won't have any performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Even if question is too broad or opinion based, I'd like to post answer:

1. It is ok to use both method (redirect and output escaping), as these actions provides different intent (validation and output). Later, it will be easier for you or somebody else to copy the style, when they will output other variable (which was not validated) or add only validation to variable (even is this variable is not printed).
2. Don't use htmlspecial chars to output javascript - it is wrong, as html and javascript has different special symbols.
3. Always use bindparam, doesn't matter where you get data and how you validated them. It is not only safer, but usually faster and cleaner (than string concatenation)

Comment: This isn't suppose to be about the examples, it's more about if it's redundant to check variables more then once. But Anyway, thanks. I replaced the htmlentities with a preg_replace that remove everything expect numbers.

Comment: @Yemto if you need only numbers use `intval` or `floatval`